# Reactjs: Change state in render only some times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, offlineapps

It is my understanding that you are not supposed to change states in the render function cause that would cause and infinite re render or the component.

This makes perfect sense, but I find myself in a particular situation. I am building an offline application and I am using an offline storage system to retrieve data. Now, whenever a method is called to get certain data, cache is checked, if it is not expired the component will be able to access the data and therefore nothing happens, but if it is expired there is a call to the API, the data is updated and the interested components re-rendered.

These methods will change the state of the component the first time they are called because they are going to the API  grabbing the new data and re-rendering, and then they will not change the state anymore because the data will already be in cache.

Now, I could call these methods in component will mount, and that is what I am doing now, but if I am forced to re call them, I need to unmount and remount the components. Is this the only possible way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the first step is understanding that state management and rendering needs to be decoupled which you got already.

Now what you can do is consider your external state/cache element as an observable object (ie. I want to do something like `observableObject.listen('change', onChangeHandler)`; you can use EventsEmitter from the `events` library). [You do that listening on `componentDidMount` and clean up in `componentWillUnmout`.](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) That `onChangeHandler` is very simple: `this.setState({ value: observableObject.value })` which will trigger a component re-render which should be a pure function that outputs DOM nodes depending on `props` being passed and it's own `state`.

This means that your logic of checking if the cache is invalid is not on a per request of the value (inside rendering) but rather think of the object as self contained. It regularly checks if itself needs to notify its listeners that it changed. Since JS does not do parallel execution you don't have to deal with threads and synchronization. You know that at the point in time your render function executes it will have the latest value. If after rendering the logic that checks for cache executes and it sees that it needs to be updated it simply notifies as said earlier its listeners and that makes your component re-render because your `onChangeHandler` changed the `state`.

Hope I helped.

Comment: Ok, so I am already calling render() from the cache when something is changed. The solution you are proposing is that instead of simply calling render I can call a method in the component that updates the cache as needed and than calls cache?

Comment: Yeah, you basically create a "link" between that external `cache/state` and your own component instance `state`. If one changes the other one gets notified. Something like this:

`this.props.myCache.listen('change', this.onCacheChange)` and 
`this.onCacheChange = () => this.setState({ value: this.props.myCache.getValue() });` More info about React [`setState`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html).

Comment: Yeah, but this already happens. So, lets say something clears the cache. Cache triggers a rerender of all the pages that are interested. the problem is that methods that are called in componentWillMount, need to be recalled and go call the API again and change the cache that in turn will cause a re-render. Did this suggest me a solution though of not only re rendering from cache but calling a method in my component that asynchronously calls api and then re renders.

Comment: `componentWillMount` should only be executed once. A re-render because of a change of state does not unmount a component. Your cache update should only notify listeners. Your business logic inside that handle is per component. In my example I used a single `setState` call. That method can be more complex. I don't see how you see an infinite re-render case.

Comment: right, I think that's what you were suggesting then. I will select this as the answer.

Comment: I believe you missunderstood what I meant by `myCache.getValue()`. That method simply returns the value (simple getter) and nothing more (e.g. doing a cache check to update). I was describing the observable pattern for synchronization of your component and new state of cache.